# How to Merge Multiple MP4 Videos files in single file

Tags: java, mp4, video-editing

I need to merge the multiple MP4 videos file to a single file using java. Can any one tell me how to merge videos. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which software or library are you planning to use?  This is not the right place to ask for recommendations.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have no idea that which library should be use to merge the videos.But this task should be done using java.

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not mention format it is hard to give advice, but for mp4 this seems to be a good alternative. Even includes example of merging files.

Code taken from link:

```
MovieCreator mc = new MovieCreator();
Movie video = mc.build(Channels.newChannel(AppendExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-video.mp4")));
Movie audio = mc.build(Channels.newChannel(AppendExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/count-english-audio.mp4")));

List videoTracks = video.getTracks();
video.setTracks(new LinkedList());

List audioTracks = audio.getTracks();

for(Track videoTrack:videoTracks){
    video.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTrack, videoTrack));
}

for(Track audioTrack:audioTracks){
    video.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTrack, audioTrack));
}

IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(String.format("output.mp4")));
out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
fos.close();
```

https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4parser/wikis/AppendTracks.wiki

Comment: Thanks Vixen for help.yes i am talking about mp4, can you send the example code to merging the several MP4 videos . i didnt find the example code in the given link. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello what is MovieCreator ?

Comment: @RobbyPatel, I would assume it is part of the mp4parser

Comment: @ViktorMellgren ok i have no idea of mp4parser can you give me example

Comment: i have issue in merging 2 .mp4 in android

Comment: This code doesn't stitch movies, but adds them as tracks on top of each other. The total movie length wil be the same...