# Can i add any independent two mp4 files in java without any corruptness or data loss?

Tags: java, jsp, ffmpeg, mp4, mp4parser

I have tried "copy /b "C:\File.mp4" + "C:\File1.mp4" CombinedFile.mp4" windows command but not worked. I have also tried ffmpeg command but the second file got corrupted. Can any one refer me that how it work internally? On what factors merge depends? 
Software add any two files perfectly. Is there any way that I can add two mp4 files in Java/jsp without any dependency?

Comment: here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36980332/32090

Comment: I have tried below code but not worked. Please help